# a non linear curve that returns values between 0 and 1 but the x axis range is very long.

Tags: curves, mathematical-modeling, plane-curves

I am new to mathematical modelling and trying to understand how I can fit a non linear curve for my requirement below

- The curve should increase from 0 and finish at 1 within the given range of `x`. X axis is time and it starts at 9 am and finishes at 4 pm. (can be different start time and end time for other events).
- at the start of the time i.e. 9 am i should get a value of 0. At the end of the curve i.e. 4 pm, I should get a value of 1.
- as the time progresses, initially the growth is slower and as the end time approaches, the the growth rate should increase. (function of remaining time).

for eg: curve can range between [0,0] to [10000,1] or [0,0] to [1000000,1]

I found many functions that return value between 0 and 1 for a very small range of x. I am not sure how to do this for a large range of x.

I look at time in total milliseconds, but I can also check the time in hours that will reduce the X range a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a function that works for some range of $x$, you can get it to work for another range of $x$ by replacing $x$ in your function with $kx$ for some $k$ (e.g. $0.05x$ or $20x$). (Assume for simplicity you start at $x=0$.) To get it for a larger range of $x$, use a value of $k$ that is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: ah yes.. thank you very much. I was able to play with the curves on online calculator and i am able to come up with the expected curvature. I am going to use `(a^x-1)/(a-1)` .. with an appropriate coefficient for x.